How do I build Weighted Regression in Python if I have a weight column and separate column for dependent and Independent variables?
I have a perfectly running regression model where the dependent and independent variables are parsing through data frames. I want to add weights to it in % format and have added the values in a new column.
How do I create a new regression model and equation for each independent entry with the weights I have assigned to them in a separate data frame?
df = pd.read_excel('Weighted Test.xlsx')
grouped = df.groupby('sc')
sc = []
region = []
equations = []
m_value = []
c_value = []
df['Avg_actual_cube'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['Actual_TPH'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['Weight'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
grouped.head()

Output:
    sc  Region  Week of balance_day Year of balance_day Actual_TPH  Avg_actual_cube Weight
0   ABQ5    West    Week 53 2023    122.443157  0.490000    0.1
1   ABQ5    West    Week 36 2023    96.074478   0.445714    0.2
2   ABQ5    West    Week 22 2024    87.164843   0.510000    0.3

If I define the weights in a separate dataframe and run the regression , it throws me an error. Can someone confirm , what am i missing?
sample_weight=df['Weight']

for group_name, group_data in grouped:
X = group_data\['Avg_actual_cube'\].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = group_data\['Actual_TPH'\].values
weighted_model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y,sample_weight)
sc.append(group_name)
region.append(group_data['Region'].values[0])
equations.append('TPH = {:.2f}cube+ {:.2f}'.format(model.coef_[0], model.intercept_))
m_value.append(model.coef_[0])
c_value.append(model.intercept_)`

Output Error:
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
          3 y = group_data['Actual_TPH'].values
          4 weighted_model = LinearRegression()
    ----> 5 model.fit(X, y,sample_weight)
          7 sc.append(group_name)
          8 region.append(group_data['Region'].values[0])
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:667, in LinearRegression.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
        662 X, y = self._validate_data(
        663     X, y, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, y_numeric=True, multi_output=True
        664 )
        666 if sample_weight is not None:
    --> 667     sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X, dtype=X.dtype)
        669 X, y, X_offset, y_offset, X_scale = self._preprocess_data(
        670     X,
        671     y,
       (...)
        676     return_mean=True,
        677 )
        679 if sample_weight is not None:
        680     # Sample weight can be implemented via a simple rescaling.
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1565, in _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X, dtype, copy)
       1562         raise ValueError("Sample weights must be 1D array or scalar")
       1564     if sample_weight.shape != (n_samples,):
    -> 1565         raise ValueError(
       1566             "sample_weight.shape == {}, expected {}!".format(
       1567                 sample_weight.shape, (n_samples,)
       1568             )
       1569         )
       1571 return sample_weight
    
    ValueError: sample_weight.shape == (5967,), expected (52,)!



Couple things: (1) please provide some sample code-formatted data that allows us to reproduce your issue rather than an image, (2) please paste your traceback with code formatting instead of an image. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example for more helpful details.

sorry its my first post here. Does this help?

@IanThompson just checking if you need anymore details?
